# How to find resistor from colour coding

Tags: resistors, resistance, soldering, colour-coding

While repairing my soldering iron I damaged a resistor.

I need to know the value of this resistor.

How can I find the value from its colour code?

[image]

Comment: Even if you don't understand color codes, what prevents you for picking up an ohm meter and measure it? This site is for electrical engineering, not "ask an engineer".

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" has never been more fitting.

Answer (score 4):

Start with the number of color bands.  Yours has four bands.

A resistor with four bands has three for the value and one for the tolerance.

The tolerance band is always the right most, and is usually spaced further from the other bands.

That means you need to turn your resistor around.

[image]

Now reading from left to right, you have blue, gray, orange, gold.

From memory, these are the color values:

0. Black
1. Brown
2. Red
3. Orange
4. Yellow
5. Green
6. Blue
7. Violet
8. Gray
9. White

Tolerance is 5% (gold.) Silver would be 10%, and no tolerance band means 20%.

Reading your values, I get 6 (blue) 8 (gray) 3 (orange.)

The third band is the multiplier.  Orange is 3 zeros - that is, multiply by 1000.

Your resistor is a 68 kiloohm resistor with 5% tolerance.

---

Colors are tricky.  Heat can change them, and photos don't always capture them correctly.

Check the value against the [E-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers) to see if your combination is really used.  That can help you decode colors that aren't clear.

In your case, I'm pretty sure of the tolerance being 5%.  That's the [E24 series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers#Lists)

The blue band is pretty certain, and so is orange.  The one in the middle looks kind of green but also kind of grey.

E24 has 68 (blue, gray) but not 65 (blue green,) so the middle band has to be gray.

---

There are calculators to do the decoding for you.  They are easily found on the internet.

[Wikipedia has a page on the various color coding schemes.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code)

Answer (score 1):

A google search turned up a dozen results: https://www.mouser.com/technical-resources/conversion-calculators/resistor-color-code-calculator?gclid=CjwKCAiAtK79BRAIEiwA4OskBoYzOw6cS6UT08Lgup-8PD1fVWpyjcs3gee_zKlh_g5VKpnUGWOyXxoCJIoQAvD_BwE

If I see the colors correctly, 1st Blue, 2nd Green, 3rd Orange and 4th Gold (tolerance) = 65 kOhms 5% tolerance.  If the second band is gray and not green, as the other Answer said, then it's 68 KOhms.

At any given time in the future you type in Google "How to find resistor from colour coding" there will be at least a dozen options.

[image]
[image]